# Accordian hide/show layout isn't working well in IE7

Tags: javascript, accordion, show-hide

there's this piece of code on our web site that dynamically creates a new div with additional videos that are hidden (or shown) when you click on the hide/show button. The problem is that in IE7, the thumbnails aren't loaded onto the page properly - they show up on top of the link text instead of on the left, like the rest of the thumbnails in the top accordion div.

There's an examply on this page:

http://www.asme.org/kb/news---articles/media/2012/05/video-early-disease-detection-using-nanotechnology

I've fixed some of the css issues, but i think the problem here isn't CSS - it's the javascript code that's on the article.js page.

Can anybody point me in the direction of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the element doesn't have a visible container at the time the image is inserted, so it throws it in at the very top of the container, and doesn't respect the rules defined.

I'd play around with inserting it after the container is visible, or try changing the traits during/after the slide down occurs... I know that's pretty generic, but that's my best advice for the time being. I hope this helps some.

Comment: Thanks @emeacham, I'll explore making changes to the javascript based on your answer. Thanks much!